# Where does vagrant (PuPHPet used ) store data when I install meteor?

Tags: meteor, vagrant, puphpet

I've used PuPHPet to set up a development environment and did "vagrant ssh" to get into the machine. After that I installed meteor via curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh, which worked as expexcted. I thought it would install it to the sync folder I have set up but it doesn't seem to be there. Can I find the file structure of the virtualized machine on my Windows PC?

How does it work? If meteor tells me I can access my meteor app via localhost:3000 how do I access this on my Windows PC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with vagrant and windows, but give this a try.

1. Login with `vagrant ssh`
2. Open terminal and type `hostname --ip-address`
3. Paste `<yourip> localhost` in your hosts file on your windows machine `system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Now, all your localhost requests in your browser are send to your vagrant box. I'm not sure if Meteors standard port works with vagrant, so try something like `meteor -p 2000` or `meteor -p 8080`

If you want something like myapp.dev in your browser, you have to use virtual hosts. I'm only familiar with apaches virtual host system, but meteor is using nodejs so i don't know, what would be the best practice here. :/

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. PuPHPet sets up a custom IP I guess. Anyway, the IP you get with hostname --ip-address is not the correct one. The correct one (if using the standard parameters of PuPHPet) is 192.168.56.101. So this works in the hosts file for example:

192.168.56.101 awesome.dev
In your vagrant sync folder you have the awesome folder, where the files are hosted when accessing awesome.dev

So I got that figured out. Now however I don't know how to install meteor in this directory.